# When I read a PW in bash without echo, is the PW stored anywhere in log files?

Tags: bash, security, ssh, passwords

When I

```
stty -echo
read -p "Password:" PW
stty echo
```

in a bash script, and then give `$PW` to SSH, is the password stored anywhere in a log file?

I'm asking because I'm writing a script that first connects to my GIT server via ssh, creates a new repo and then locally tells GIT to clone it. Until now the user has to enter his password twice. It would be really nice if I could first store it in a variable so he's being asked only once.

Comment: Use public key authentication instead of a password.

Comment: I just realized that SSH doesn't take a password parameter. D'OH.. Yes I'll use a key file. Sorry for posting this as my first question here :)

Comment: @adrifromhh You could do it with `sshpass`. However it is _ultra_ __highly__ recommended to use public key instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is read from standard input, so only receiving process (bash `read` built-in) will read it. Bash will then store read data in `PW` variable and, as it is not exported, it will not be sent to any child process. It will be cleared at bash end. However, it may still be on memory until shut down.

Comment: I will use key files now, but still interesting to know! Thanks.